# Authentication token manipulation error when expiring password (passwd --expire)

Tags: arch-linux, login, systemd

On a fresh Arch Linux installation, I'm trying to require the user to change password on first log in. I expire the password using `passwd --expire username`, but the user can the no longer log in. This message is shown:

```
You are required to change your password immediately (administrator enforced)

Authentication token manipulation error
```

After a few seconds, it returns to the login prompt.

What causes this error, can can it be fixed to allow the user to change password?

I get the same behavior whether I set a password, or delete the password with `passwd --delete`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was curious about that behavior so I tested it on my machine.

## Reproduction

1. I create a new user

   ```
   # useradd -m -s /bin/bash test
   ```
2. I create a dummy password for it

   ```
   # passwd test
   Geben Sie ein neues Passwort ein: 
   Geben Sie das neue Passwort erneut ein:
   ```
3. Test what I did so far into another terminal

   ```
   $ su - test
   Passwort:
   $ # I'm in.
   $ exit # I'm out.
   ```
4. Back to my root terminal, I try to do what you did...

   ```
   # passwd --expire test
   passwd: Passwortablauf-Informationen geändert.
   ```
5. Back to my normal terminal, I try to connect with the new user.

   ```
   $ su - test
   Passwort: 
   You are required to change your password immediately (administrator enforced)
   su: Fehler beim Ändern des Authentifizierungstoken
   ```

   Interesting, I get the same as yourself.

## Husking

So I was curious so I looked into the manual

```
# LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 man passwd  #Comment# LC_ALL is needed because otherwise, I get the manual in german.
```

And curiously it says:

```
-e, --expire
       Immediately expire an account's password. This in effect can force a user to change their password at the
       user's next login.
```

I concluded that it's strange that the described behavior is not working...

---

So as I know `pam.d` is responsible for the login I looked for it into the journal.

```
# journalctl -g pam -xe
```

In the log, I saw the following.

```
Jul 28 xx:xx:xx funilrys su[xxxxx]: pam_unix(su-l:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=1000 euid=0 tty=pts/4 ruser=funilrys rhost=  user=test
Jul 28 xx:xx:xx funilrys su[xxxxx]: pam_unix(su-l:account): expired password for user test (root enforced)
Jul 28 xx:xx:xx funilrys su[xxxxx]: pam_warn(su-l:chauthtok): function=[pam_sm_chauthtok] flags=0x4020 service=[su-l] terminal=[pts/4] user=[test] ruser=[funilrys] rhost=[<unknown>]
```

**Note: As I log in with `su` the `su-l` is the service which is used.**

That means that `pam.d` works properly but it does not handle the password change.

---

But I wasn't convinced, so I tested with SSH (I leave to you the SSH configuration) and it worked.

```
$ ssh -p xxxxx test@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Passwort: 
You are required to change your password immediately (administrator enforced)
Ändern des Passworts für test.
Current password: 
Geben Sie ein neues Passwort ein: 
Geben Sie das neue Passwort erneut ein: 
$
```

---

I asked myself, where is the difference?

What I found is that the `/etc/pam.d/sshd` file has this line

```
password  include   system-remote-login
```

So as my service was `su-l` I added that line to `/etc/pam.d/su-l`

Then tried again.

```
$ su - test
Passwort: 
You are required to change your password immediately (administrator enforced)
Ändern des Passworts für test.
Current password: 
Geben Sie ein neues Passwort ein: 
Geben Sie das neue Passwort erneut ein:
```

And it worked!

## Conclusion

If you add the following line into `/etc/pam.d/login`, `/etc/pam.d/su-l` or other configuration depending on the service you use. The user will be able to change their password on next login.

```
password  include   system-remote-login
```

## Recommendation (Edit 1)

In my analysis, I went through but after looking deep into it, I have to admit that even if `system-remote-login` is working, we should avoid it because it was actually thought for SSH.

So, I recommend anybody who meets this issue to add the following line (instead) into `/etc/pam.d/login`, `/etc/pam.d/su-l` or other configuration depending on the service you use.

```
password  include   system-local-login
```

Comment: Amazing analysis! It works!

Comment: @larsch You may consider my recommendation/edit instead of what I previously stated. Cheers!